# Global scss styles not getting applied with single-spa-Angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, single-spa-angular

The global css present in the styles.scss file is not getting applied.
I have used single-spa in the application

Below is my index.html file-

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <base href="/"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="/src/styles.scss" type="text/scss" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using single-spa version 5.9.4.
I tried getting the global styles from the angular.json file but for one of the MFEs the global scss styles are not getting applied

Comment: should be "<link href="styles.scss" type="text/scss" rel="stylesheet" />". Remember: Angular create a bundles in a "dist folder" (or in memory) with the elements on assets folder and a index.html and .js and .css bundles. NOT in src (src is not exist for the app Angular)

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this in `main.ts` and `main.single-spa.ts`.

```
/// @ts-ignore
require('src/styles.css?ngGlobalStyle');
```

It's a knowed behaviour of single-spa.

Also refer to this [Single-SPA Styles](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/ecosystem-angular#styles)

Comment: *if you are using styles.scss be careful to add the file with the correct extension

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
This specific issue has been resolved in the newer version of single-spa-angular (v9.0.1). The newer version of single-spa-angular event supports upto angular version 17. https://www.npmjs.com/package/single-spa-angular

It is a known issue in single page application in angular (v15). You can see the reported issue here: https://github.com/single-spa/single-spa-angular/issues/471 and there is a workaround fix to this issue here, you can see at https://github.com/single-spa/single-spa-angular/issues/463#issuecomment-1582486882

Comment: No, Hasrh it's not a issue. You can not refer to "src" folder because when Angular create the app only have an assets folder. NOTE: **NOT** put .css in assets folder, instead of add the .css in angular.json to allow Angular create a bundle.css joining all the .css

Comment: You can actually try reproducing it. Use single-spa-angular 8 version with angular 15 as parcel. I have tried to find the solution, but just workarounds are there.

Comment: @Priyanshu can you please tell me the version of angular you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You should look in angular.json if it's not correct check a parent folder of src maybe another style.scss in there.

Comment: The host project is having multiple projects with its respective  styles.scss so for each module how to load the MFE application's that is global scss to take precedence over the host app using  single-spa-framework angular.json